# python string template with key as expression

Tags: python, string, stringtemplate

I am using string template to replace placeholders. My current scenario is to have variable for the key instead of the string to be replaced.

Below is an example of what i am trying to achieve.

```
import traceback
from string import Template

def test_substitute():
    try:
        tpl = Template("My $testname is ...")
        name = 'testname'
        tpl_str = tpl.substitute(name='test')
        print(tpl_str)
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()

if __name__=="__main__":
    test_substitute()
```

In the above example, name is a variable that holds any string like 'testname' or 'testname1' but i the key cannot be a variable as it consider a whole string.

Is there a way to make that key as a variable?

If not i would rather go with string replace.

-Bala

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to set the key value from a var when creating the template string? In which case `tpl = Template(f"My {testname} is ...")` (if python 3.8 or above of course)

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
import traceback
from string import Template

def test_substitute():
    try:
        tpl = Template("My $testname is ...")
        name = 'testname'
        tpl_str = tpl.substitute(**{name: 'test'})
        print(tpl_str)
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()

if __name__=="__main__":
    test_substitute()
```